# Typehinting array of models

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, type-hinting

I was wondering if you can typehint an array of models in php (more explicitly Laravel).

A code example:

```
use App\User;

public function index(User $user)
{
    // do something with the user
}
```

My question is, is there a way to typehint an array of User models:

```
use App\User;

public function index(array User $users) //this is wrong ..
{
    // do something with the users
}
```

Comment: As it's Laravel, you could typehint Eloquent\Collection, if you're expecting results from an Eloquent query, but obviously you wouldn't know it was a Collection of Users!

Comment: Maybe extend `Eloquent\Collection` to `App\UserCollection`?

Comment: Good idea, could you broaden up on how you would do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No, you can't do this**. The best you can do is to typehint the parameter as an array. You can read more about type-hinting in PHP here: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration

**UPDATE**
In PHP 5.6+ you can use variable length argument lists to achieve what you want. Check the [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46932906/1090395)

Answer (score 9):

In PHP 5.6+ you can use [variable length argument lists](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list) to achieve what you want.

You unpack the variable as you call the function, and the function uses variadic parameters in its signature. So instead of passing one array of `User` objects, you unpack an `array` or `Collection` of `User` objects, and all of them are checked against the typehint you provide.

**Example:**

```
function deleteUsers(User ...$users)
{
    // delete the users here
}

$users = [$user1, $user2, $user3];

deleteUsers(...$users);
```

Unpacking will work both on a regular `array` and on Laravel `Collection` objects, or any other `Traversable` variable or literal, to feed into the argument list.

This is the equivalent of doing the following:

```
deleteUsers($user1, $user2, $user3);
```

Comment: Don't understand why this isn't the accepted answer or why it had 0 votes :eye_roll_emoji:

Comment: Thanks Robert. You'll have to ask @rvandersteen :)

Answer (score 1):

I know an answer was already accepted, but this is half-possible depending on how well your IDE implements phpDoc (PhpStorm supports this for sure but we had issues getting Eclipse to support it last year).

phpDoc supports typed arrays via a `Class[]` syntax. So you could do:

```
use App\User;

/**
 * @var User[] $user
 */
public function index(array $users)
{
    // do something with the users
}
```

That won't restrict someone from passing an array of non-`User` objects into `index` (as type-hinting an `array` type would if they passed in a string), but it will provide guidance to them on what is expected and it will allow you get code-hinting when you do:

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
    $user->dele // Depending on IDE, this will code hint/complete "delete()"
}
```

[phpDoc Array Documentation](http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/guides/types.html#arrays)